# What time of the year is the cheapest to cruise in/around North America?

Tags: budget, planning, cruising, north-america

What times of the years are optimal for getting the best prices on cruises within North America?

Comment: Leaving from North America or only stopping in North America?

Comment: Only Stopping in north america. I.e. Not asian, transatlantic cruises european cruises

Comment: What sort of cruise? What length did you have in mind? And as silent1mezzo says, from where and around where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I have heard/read, people always seem to say that Fall, such as September and onwards, is the best time to cruise (particularly for the Caribbean) for the following reasons:

1. School has started, so there are less family vacations and college kids looking for cruises.
2. The worry of hurricanes puts some people off.
3. Lack of vacations after Labor Day and before Thanksgiving.

I don't have any hard data to back that up though.

Keep in mind some places, like cruises to Alaska, are only around during certain times of the year so there's no 'time of year' for them to be cheaper than others.

And finally, the cheapest deals I can usually find are from last minute cruise deals, but you have to be ready to go within a week or two.  Those are typically much cheaper because the cruise ship wants to fill up their vacant spots.

Comment: how do you search for last minute cruise deals? Do you use any website for that? If you do, please take a look at my question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43168/how-can-i-do-an-online-broad-search-for-cruise-trips. Could you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer here to be

- Mid to late January. Typically starts a week or two after the New Year's rush ends. Weather might not be great, however.
- Mid to late September. Most people are back in school by now (people seem less likely to skip that first week). Still warm (and hurricane season) but it seems that prices are rebounded by the first week of Oct.