# How can I do an online broad search for cruise trips?

Tags: online-resources, planning, cruising

I like to travel in cruise ships, but for me it's usually hard to decide on an itinerary. I've never found a web site that allows me to compare cruise trips, so I have to search in many cruise companies ([Costa](http://www.costacruise.com/), [MSC](http://www.msccruises.com/), [Royal Caribbean](http://www.royalcaribbean.com/)...) and compare their fares and itineraries.

It seems to me that cruise planning is not as advanced as flying. Last time I took a Costa cruise (it was a little over 1 year ago) I couldn't buy it online! I had to go to a travel agent and buy through it. Even though, I suspect there should be a website to help those that want to cruise, but I'm just not aware of.

Specifically, I'm looking for a tool like [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/), [Adioso](http://adioso.com/), [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/) (and the like), that would allow me to enter a date (or a date range) and places (perhaps a country or a region) and search for cruise ships that would be in those places within the date range supplied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried any of the following?

http://www.cruisingexcursions.com/

http://www.expedia.com.au/cruises

Happy cruising!

Comment: Expedia seems like a good search tool! I´ll definitely try it before my next cruise!

Answer (score 4):

This website is very useful

http://www.cruisetimetables.com

You can see departures from individual ports, but if you have a specific destination in mind you can select a different tab and see cruises that call at that location.

It is date based so has some restrictions in use.

It also has links to cruise agents for booking, however I think the pricing is not that competitive so shop around.

Answer (score 0):

The online portal [vacations to go](http://www.vacationstogo.com) has a [custom search](http://www.vacationstogo.com/custom.cfm) which might suit your criteria. You have the option to specify the following search criteria:

- Region
- Time Range
- Minimum/maximum number of nights
- Type of stateroom. (Ocean view, balcony, suite)
- Price range
- Company (both include and exclude)
- Cruise ship
- Passenger capacity of the ship
- Ports visited (both include and exclude)
- Departure Port

Note that you have to give your particulars to see any results. However, no email confirmation is needed, so using fake particulars should be possible if you are worried about giving out information.

I haven't actually used the website before. There seems to be some [mixed opinions](http://www.fodors.com/community/cruises/anyone-ever-used-vacations-to-go.cfm) on their service quality, ranging from very good to very bad, but as long as you only use it to look up cruises, I don't see much risk involved.

*Note: this answer is adapted from another [answer of mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/53565/8363)*