# Online cruise search tool allowing to exclude some ports

Tags: online-resources, planning, cruising

This question is a narrowing from [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43168/how-can-i-do-an-online-broad-search-for-cruise-trips). When searching online for cruises, ther are some ports that I just can't or don't wish to go. For instance, I might not have a visa for a specific country, or simply I've been to one port, didn't like and prefer not to go there anymore.

Does anyone know an online cruise search tool that allows to **exclude** some ports in the itinerary?

Comment: You can try a reverse: http://ports.cruisett.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online portal [vacations to go](http://www.vacationstogo.com) offers this possibility on their [custom search](http://www.vacationstogo.com/custom.cfm). You have the option to choose up to two ports to exclude.

[image: Caption of the 'exclude port' search feature]

Note that you have to give your particulars to see any results. However, no email confirmation is needed, so using fake particulars should be possible if you are worried about giving out information.

I haven't actually used the website before. There seems to be some [mixed opinions](http://www.fodors.com/community/cruises/anyone-ever-used-vacations-to-go.cfm) on their service quality, ranging from very good to very bad, but as long as you only use it to look up cruises, I don't see much risk involved.

Comment: You should also add this to the broad search for Cruises.  Plus mixed opinion's link seems MIA

Comment: Thanks, rectified that. I'll add an answer to the other question later.